# Ignoring the normalising constant in Bayesian MCMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood

This post relates to my original question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399323/combining-unbalanced-likelihoods-in-a-process-based-model), but this time focusing on a more fundamental misunderstanding of how MCMC actually works.

When using Bayesian MCMC for parameter inference with a single model, it is usual to ignore the "evidence" integral and write:

$$P(\theta | D) \propto P(D | \theta) P(\theta)$$

For numerical reasons, it is also common to work with logarithms:

$$ln[P(\theta | D)] \propto ln[P(D | \theta)] + ln[P(\theta)]$$

I've used this successfully on a number of occasions, typically using Python and [emcee](http://dfm.io/emcee/current/). However, for reasons explained in my [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399323/combining-unbalanced-likelihoods-in-a-process-based-model), I've recently been wondering about "normalising" my likelihood by dividing it by the number of observations (I realise this probably sounds odd, but please see my other question for why I thought it was worth a try).

My likelihood assumes i.i.d. Gaussian errors, so my log-likelihood is just the sum of the individual data likelihoods. My prior is **uniform** and I'm currently using an **improper** log-prior function, which simply returns zero if the parameter values are "within range" and `'-inf'` otherwise.

I initially assumed that dividing by the number of data points wouldn't make any difference, because the RHS is still *proportional to* the log-posterior:

$$ln[P(\theta | D)] \propto \frac{1}{n}ln[P(D | \theta)] + ln[P(\theta)]$$

(My prior only ever returns 0 or `'-inf'`, so multiplying that by $1/n$ makes no difference).

However, when I re-run my MCMC, I get *very* different results. As a sense check, I tried a simple OLS linear regression using the same code.

With my original (not normalised) likelihood, I get sensible results: the MCMC recovers the "true" parameters and the 95% CI broadly agrees with the Frequentist results from `'statsmodels'`:

[image: Original (not normalised) likelihood]

However, with the "normalised" likelihood, I get very different (and obviously wrong) results:

[image]

I *think* I understand why this is, at least from the point of view of a simple Metropolis algorithm. The probability of accepting the proposed jump, $x_{i+1}$, compared to the current location, $x_i$, is:

$$\alpha = \frac{P(x_{i+1})}{P(x_i)}$$

Which, re-writing in terms of my log-posterior, $L$, becomes:

$$\alpha = \frac{exp(L(x_{i+1}))}{exp(L(x_i))} = exp(L(x_{i+1}) - L(x_i))$$

On the other hand, for my "normalised" version, all the likelihoods are divided by $n$, so this becomes:

$$\alpha = [exp(L(x_{i+1}) - L(x_i))]^\frac{1}{n}$$

which is different, and might explain why my uncertainty bounds suddenly become much larger. (I understand that emcee is more sophisticated than just basic Metropolis, but I guess a similar principle applies?).

**My question:**

**What am I missing/misunderstanding to reconcile these two results, please?** On the one hand, it's OK to ignore the "normalising constant" in Bayes' equation, because anything proportional to the log-posterior is sufficient. On the other hand, multiplying the log-posterior by a constant $\frac{1}{n}$ seems to have a dramatic effect on my results?

Thank you!

Comment: If you look at the denominator in Bayes theorem on the log scale (which you're working on) it would involve *subtracting* a constant, not dividing by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying the likelihood by a constant makes no difference, as you state. You can take $\tilde L(x)=\frac1n L(x)$ with $K>0$ and obtain the same result.

When you take the log, you will then get $\log\tilde L(x) = \log L(x) -n$: on the log scale, you can *add* a constant, but not multiply by a constant.

Multiplying the log-likelihood by a constant $k$ (or equivalently raise the likelihood to the $k$th power) gives what is called a tempered likelihood. When $0<k<1$, the tempered likelihood is flatter than the likelihood. The mode is preserved, but the tails of the distribution are heavier.

Comment: Gah! Of course, apologies - basic algebra fail :-( I had a feeling it would be something blindingly obvious, but nevertheless spent half the afternoon tying myself in knots! Thanks to you and @Glen_b for putting me back on track!